# Testing dao with junit in Spring MVC project

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

I've just started my journey with Spring, so I'm a newbie.

I'm trying to write tests to DAO.

When I run tests the stack trace returns:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private pl.com.tt.persistence.TestEntityDaoJPA pl.com.tt.tests.TestPersistenceDAO.testEntityDaoJPA; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [pl.com.tt.persistence.TestEntityDaoJPA] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

It looks like I shouldn't use @Autowired above TestEntityDAO implementation. When I delete @Autowire annotation stack trace returns error with invocation method testEntityDaoJPA.getAll(sql).

This is my test class:

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class TestPersistenceDAO extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityDaoJPA testEntityDaoJPA;

    @Test
    public void testDAO(){
        String sql = "SELECT r FROM TestEntity r WHERE ROWNUM<200";
        testEntityDaoJPA.getAll(sql);
    }
}
```

My DAO class:

```
    @Component
public class TestEntityDaoJPA implements TestEntityDao {

    @Autowired
    @PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public List<TestEntity> getAll(String sql){
        TypedQuery<TestEntity> q = em.createQuery(sql, TestEntity.class );
        List<TestEntity> result = q.getResultList();

              return result;
    }
}
```

XML context file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="pl.com.tt.tests" />
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.80.128:1521:orcl" />
        <property name="username" value="findfnorg" />
        <property name="password" value="findfnorg" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="pl.com.tt.tests" />
        <property name="persistenceProviderClass"
            value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" />
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>



<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: So, if you are intending to test the instance of the class created by Spring then `@Autowired` is appropriate, you just need to ensure that your context has an instance of that class. The REAL question here though is that do you REALLY intend you JUnit test to use the database at `192.168.80.128:1521:orcl`?

Answer (score 3):

Your package is not scanned by spring.

You indicate:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="pl.com.tt.tests" />
```

But TestEntityDaoJPA  is in pl.com.tt.persistence. So this package is not scanned and no bean is created.

Try to change to:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="pl.com.tt.tests,pl.com.tt.persistence" />
```